# Div not adjusting to content

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I have a container with three articles in them that I am trying to get them to auto size depending on the content. The articles seem to auto size correctly however my container is not getting bigger as the articles get bigger, and also my footer is overlapping my container instead of pushing everything down. How can I make the container get bigger as the articles inside get bigger and push everything else down?

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Base Temp</title>
<link href="Layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript">
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="MM_preloadImages('media/HorButton2Hov.png','media/HorButton3Hov.png','media/HorButton4Hov.png','media/HorButton1Hov.png')">       

<div id="Container">
<div id="Header">
  <div id="HeaderName">Company Name/Slogan
  </div><!--END HeaderName-->

 <div id="Logo"></div><!--END Logo-->

 <div id="HorMenu">

  <div id="HorButtons">
    <div id="HorButton1"><a href="BUTTON1URL" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Button1','','media/HorButton1Hov.png',1)"><img src="media/HorButton1.png" alt="" width="170" height="33" id="Button1"></a> </div><!--END HorButton1-->
    <div id="HorButton2"><a href="BUTTON2URL" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Button2','','media/HorButton2Hov.png',1)"><img src="media/HorButton2.png" alt="" width="170" height="33" id="Button2"></a>
    </div><!--END HorButton2-->
    <div id="HorButton3"><a href="BUTTON3URL" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Button3','','media/HorButton3Hov.png',1)"><img src="media/HorButton3.png" alt="" width="170" height="33" id="Button3"></a>
    </div><!--END HorButton3-->
    <div id="HorButton4"><a href="BUTTON4URL" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Button4','','media/HorButton4Hov.png',1)"><img src="media/HorButton4.png" alt="" width="170" height="33" id="Button4"></a>
    </div><!--END HorButton4-->
  </div><!--END HorButtons"-->
  </div><!--END HorMenu-->

</div><!--///////END Header\\\\\\\\\-->

<div id="VerMenu"><img src="media/VerMenu.png"  alt=""/>
</div><!--END VerMenu"-->

<div id="VerRightMenu"><img src="media/VerMenu.png"  alt=""/>
</div><!--END VerMenuRight-->

<!--///////////START CONTENT\\\\\\\\\\\-->
<div id="Content">
<div id="LeadArticle"><h1>Heading 1</h1><h2>Heading 2</h2><p>Content here<br>
and more</p></div>
<div id="LeftArticle"><h1>Left Article</h1>
</div><!--END LeftArticle"-->
<div id="RightArticle"><h1>Right Article</h1><p>a;ldkjlak aldjf adfjl;k jflikhfkjah kldhf kjh gfkjls dfj ghkljsdfhg kjsf ghkjdf ghfur hklus hgklj klsfjgh kljsdf ghkjdsf ghkjsldf ghkjsd gfkjsdf gksdf ghkljsd ghfkjs gf</p>
</div><!--END RightArticle-->


</div><!--/////////END Content\\\\\\\\\\\-->

<div id="Footer">
<br><br><br>Designed By Jamie Horton
</div><!--END Footer-->
</div><!-- END CONTAINER -->


</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
#Container
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 1336px;
    min-height: 600px;
    background-color: #FFF9F9;
    z-index: 0;
    text-align: left;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
#Header
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 180px;
    width: 1336px;
    z-index: 10;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background-image: url(media/Header.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 1336px 180px;
}
#Logo
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 156px;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 180px;
    width: 220px;
    background-image: url(media/Logo.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
#HeaderName
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 476px;
    height: 61px;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 704px;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: xx-large;
}
#HorMenu
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 140px;
    left: 376px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 804px;
    z-index: 10;
    background-image: url(media/HorMenu.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
#HorButtons
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    left: 47px;
    height: 33px;
    width: 757px;
    z-index: 10;
    max-width: 804px;
    max-height: 33px;
}
#HorButton1 
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 33px;
    max-height: 33px;
    width: 170px;
    z-index: 10;
}
#HorButton2
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 180px;
    height: 33px;
    max-height: 33px;
    width: 170px;
    z-index: 10;
}
#HorButton3
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 360px;
    height: 33px;
    max-height: 33px;
    width: 170px;
    z-index: 10;
}
#HorButton4
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 540px;
    height: 33px;
    max-height: 33px;
    width: 170px;
    z-index: 10;
}
#VerMenu
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 180px;
    left: 156px;
    z-index: 20;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 170px;
    min-height: 250px;
}
#VerRightMenu
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 180px;
    right: 156px;
    z-index: 20;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 170px;
    min-height: 250px;
}
#Content
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 180px;
    left: 156px;
    min-height: 320px;
    width: 1024px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 30;
}
#LeadArticle
{
    background-color: #E9E6E6;
    position: relative;
    left: 170px;
    z-index:: 31;
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: x-large;
    top: 0px;
    color: #010101;
    min-height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    max-width: 654px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 25px;
    width: 654px;
}
#LeftArticle
{
    background-color: #E9E6E6;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 170px;
    z-index:: 31;
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: x-large;
    color: #010101;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    max-width: 320px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    bottom: 0%;
    width: 320px;
}
#RightArticle
{
    background-color: #E9E6E6;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    z-index:: 31;
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: x-large;
    color: #010101;
    min-height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    max-width: 320px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    right: 170px;
    width: 320px;
}
#Footer {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 1024px;
    z-index: 57;
    background-color: #2F2F2F;
    font-size: large;
    text-align: center;
    left: 156px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
h1 {
    font-size:xx-large;
}
h2 {
    font-size:x-large;
}
p {
    font-size:large;
}
```

Comment: Does height:auto; work on your container CSS?

Comment: You're supposed to give the minimum amount of code that shows the problem, not full pages.

Comment: I did add height:auto to #container and #content and that showed an additional line in the article, but it is still being covered by my footer for some reason

Comment: But wont that just put the article content on top of my footer and then you wont b able to see the footer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have way to much absolute positioning. Blocks with absolute positioning are not counted when laying out their parents. For your container to grow with its contents, the contents must not be absolutely positioned.

Next, your footer is set to stick at the bottom of the container. Add `padding-bottom: 100px` (or probably a bit more) to your container to reserve the space for the footer.

Much cleaned up fiddle, but I believe it's about what you're trying to get to:
http://jsfiddle.net/R939B/

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm finding the different positions to be confusing, I pretty much thought that absolute allowed me to place it where ever I want, which could be on top of other divs, while relative will place the divs next to each other

Comment: Absolute positioning does allow you to place a block wherever you want, but it's then completely ignored when laying out other blocks in the same parent, or the size of the parent. If you want a container to grow with the blocks it contains, they cannot be absolutely positioned. But you can still control the layout, either using `floats` or `display: inline-block` (to have blocks side-by-side rather than just below each other). If you use `float`, you need to have a `clear` after them, otherwise they get ignored as week (the fiddle uses an `:after` for that)

Answer (score 0):

Don't give them a specific height... Let the content determine the height

Comment: I got rid of all the specific heights but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a fixed width for the article div that's why the div width doesn't increase with the increase of contents.

And for the footer placement, place a `margin-bottom` of same height of footer at the previous sibling div. Also change the `position` of footer to `fixed`. In this case -

```
#Content {
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

#Footer {
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: I do not want the footer to always show on the bottom of the screen, only when the user scrolls all the way to the bottom.

Comment: Then you can use `padding-bottom: 100px` to the `#Content` div but don't use the `margin-bottom` then.